# Google Tag manager v4 giving error while implementing in android

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

While implementing GTM gettng following error

**Failed to extract the container from the resource file. Resource is a UTF-8 encoded string but doesn't contain a JSON container**

I have done coding as follow

```
TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);

    tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
    Log.v("tag", "before loading binary file ");
    PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager
            .loadContainerPreferNonDefault(CONTAINER_ID,
                    R.raw.gtm_default_container);
    Log.v("tag", "after loading binary file ");
     pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
                if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                   // Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");
                   // displayErrorToUser("error");

                    return;
                }
                ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
                ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
                containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
                startMainActivity();
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);





private static class ContainerLoadedCallback implements ContainerHolder.ContainerAvailableListener {
    @Override
    public void onContainerAvailable(ContainerHolder containerHolder, String containerVersion) {
        // We load each container when it becomes available.
        Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
        registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
    }

    public static void registerCallbacksForContainer(Container container) {
        // Register two custom function call macros to the container.
        container.registerFunctionCallMacroCallback("increment", new CustomMacroCallback());
        container.registerFunctionCallMacroCallback("mod", new CustomMacroCallback());
        // Register a custom function call tag to the container.
        container.registerFunctionCallTagCallback("custom_tag", new CustomTagCallback());
    }
}

 private static class CustomTagCallback implements FunctionCallTagCallback {
        @Override
        public void execute(String tagName, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
            // The code for firing this custom tag.
            Log.i("CuteAnimals", "Custom function call tag :" + tagName + " is fired.");
        }
    }
private static class CustomMacroCallback implements FunctionCallMacroCallback {
    private int numCalls;

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String name, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        if ("increment".equals(name)) {
            return ++numCalls;
        } else if ("mod".equals(name)) {
            return (Long) parameters.get("key1") % Integer.valueOf((String) parameters.get("key2"));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Custom macro name: " + name + " is not supported.");
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Utilities.pushOpenScreenEvent(this, "SplasScreen");
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Utilities.pushCloseScreenEvent(this, "Splashscreen");
}
```

How we can trace page views using GTM and display it in GA in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the container binary to your project? It is explained at:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#add

> Google Tag Manager uses a default container on the first run of your
>   application. The default container will cease to be used as soon as
>   the app is able to retrieve a fresh container over the network.
>
> To download and add a default container binary to your application, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign in to the Google Tag Manager web interface.
> 2. Select the Version of the container you'd like to download.
> 3. Click the Download button to retrieve the container binary.
> 4. Add the downloaded container binary file to your project as a raw resource.
>
>    - If the raw subfolder under /res/ does not exist, create it.
>    - Rename the container binary file if necessary. It consists of only lowercase letters, digits, and underscores.
>    - Copy the container binary file to the folder /res/raw.
>
> Although using the binary file is recommended, if your container does not contain rules or tags, you may choose to use a simple JSON
>   file instead.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to download `binary` file, only `json` format is available. in v4.

Comment: After adding the binary to /res/raw folder, getting the same error mentioned by OP

Answer (score 1):

You can get a binary version but after creating a variable,trigger and tag and then publish your container.
go back to versions panel,select actions drop down menu and chose download.